# My MySQL server on digitalocean keeps crashing when running some woocommerce tasks, attaching mysql error log . any idea why?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

My MySQL server keeps crashing when running some woocommerce tasks, there isn't any traffic by far , like maybe one hit per hour or less, 99% hits are because of my from the admin panel, attaching mysql error log

**server details**

1. provider - digitalocean
2. OS  - Ubuntu 19.04 LTS
3. stack - LAMP
4. MySQL version: 8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3 through PHP extension MySQLi
5. RAM - 1 GB
6. SSD is still more than 50% free

`

```
   2020-04-20T03:48:30.482071Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010080] [Server] The use of InnoDB is mandatory since MySQL 5.7. The former options like '--innodb=0/1/OFF/ON' or '--skip-innodb' are ignored.
    2020-04-20T03:48:30.482083Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010080] [Server] The use of InnoDB is mandatory since MySQL 5.7. The former options like '--innodb=0/1/OFF/ON' or '--skip-innodb' are ignored.
    2020-04-20T03:48:30.485048Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3) starting as process 6006
    2020-04-20T03:48:31.604813Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
    2020-04-20T03:48:31.624398Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
    2020-04-20T03:48:31.792352Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
    2020-04-20T03:48:32.331025Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
    2020-04-20T03:48:32.673302Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
    2020-04-20T03:48:33.334826Z 14 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:48:33.359907Z 13 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:48:33.360197Z 17 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:48:34.014307Z 17 [Warning] [MY-010756] [Server] Checking table:   './myshop/wp_options'
    2020-04-20T03:48:47.570204Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010080] [Server] The use of InnoDB is mandatory since MySQL 5.7. The former options like '--innodb=0/1/OFF/ON' or '--skip-innodb' are ignored.
    2020-04-20T03:48:47.570213Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010080] [Server] The use of InnoDB is mandatory since MySQL 5.7. The former options like '--innodb=0/1/OFF/ON' or '--skip-innodb' are ignored.
    2020-04-20T03:48:47.572172Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3) starting as process 6102
    2020-04-20T03:48:48.809895Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
    2020-04-20T03:48:48.841774Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
    2020-04-20T03:48:49.458214Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
    2020-04-20T03:48:53.419768Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
    2020-04-20T03:48:53.867082Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
    2020-04-20T03:48:59.620511Z 7 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:48:59.703179Z 24 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:48:59.752318Z 21 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:48:59.781891Z 8 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:48:59.869661Z 13 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:48:59.946611Z 19 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:49:00.001451Z 9 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:49:00.060660Z 17 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:49:00.172364Z 18 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:49:00.285342Z 12 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:49:00.381400Z 14 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:49:00.422576Z 15 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:49:00.507195Z 16 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:49:03.729147Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010080] [Server] The use of InnoDB is mandatory since MySQL 5.7. The former options like '--innodb=0/1/OFF/ON' or '--skip-innodb' are ignored.
    2020-04-20T03:49:03.729156Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010080] [Server] The use of InnoDB is mandatory since MySQL 5.7. The former options like '--innodb=0/1/OFF/ON' or '--skip-innodb' are ignored.
    2020-04-20T03:49:03.731122Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3) starting as process 6183
    2020-04-20T03:49:04.929865Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
    2020-04-20T03:49:04.984710Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
    2020-04-20T03:49:08.270242Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
    2020-04-20T03:49:08.528334Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
    2020-04-20T03:49:08.761347Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
    2020-04-20T03:49:08.840729Z 15 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:49:08.842024Z 17 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:49:08.842193Z 10 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:49:08.842413Z 11 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:49:08.842538Z 16 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:49:08.842671Z 8 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:49:08.843040Z 12 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:49:08.843322Z 9 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:49:08.843645Z 14 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:49:08.844176Z 13 [ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table './myshop/wp_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
    2020-04-20T03:49:08.850453Z 14 [Warning] [MY-010756] [Server] Checking table:   './myshop/wp_options'
    2020-04-20T03:49:33.007478Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010080] [Server] The use of InnoDB is mandatory since MySQL 5.7. The former options like '--innodb=0/1/OFF/ON' or '--skip-innodb' are ignored.
    2020-04-20T03:49:33.007487Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010080] [Server] The use of InnoDB is mandatory since MySQL 5.7. The former options like '--innodb=0/1/OFF/ON' or '--skip-innodb' are ignored.
    2020-04-20T03:49:33.009642Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3) starting as process 6293
    2020-04-20T03:49:34.320339Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
    2020-04-20T03:49:34.351618Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
    2020-04-20T03:49:36.455632Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
    2020-04-20T03:49:37.389898Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
    2020-04-20T03:49:37.666779Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
```

`

Comment: Repair table `wp_options`, have you tried?

Comment: Tried tens of times , no effect

Comment: Also converted wp_options to myISAM . No effect ..

Comment: How long can it stay on? If it's stayed on, can you access the table? If you can access the table, are you able to dump the table or will it crash midway?

Comment: I am able to access the table or create a dump ..i can Even do whole database dump ..Using just wordpress too doesn't cause a crash ...But as soon as we start working with woocommerce crashes start

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Any solutions ? it would be helpful if you have answer